# theano.test() ERROR: test_grad GradientError: numeric gradient and analytic gradient exceed tolerance

Tags: theano

I installed Theano 0.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04, ran `theano.test()` and got the following error.

What would be the possible cause of this error?

> ======================================================================
>   ERROR: test_grad (theano.tensor.tests.test_basic.ArctanhInplaceTester)
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/tests/test_basic.py", line 483, in test_grad
>       eps=_grad_eps)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tests/unittest_tools.py", line 91, in verify_grad
>       T.verify_grad(op, pt, n_tests, rng, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 1709, in verify_grad
>       abs_tol, rel_tol)
>   GradientError: GradientError: numeric gradient and analytic gradient exceed tolerance:
>           At position 4 of argument 0,
>               abs. error = 3.537018,  abs. tolerance = 0.010000
>               rel. error = 0.013429,  rel. tolerance = 0.010000
>   Exception args:
>   The error happened with the following inputs:, [array([[ 0.28898013,  0.98691875, -0.37341487],
>          [-0.83661169, -0.99454761, -0.57619613]], dtype=float32)],
>   The value of eps is:, None,
>   The out_type is:, None, Test arctanh_inplace::normal: Error occurred while computing the gradient on the following inputs: [array([[ 0.28898013,  0.98691875, -0.37341487],
>          [-0.83661169, -0.99454761, -0.57619613]], dtype=float32)]
>
> ======================================================================
>   ERROR: test_grad (theano.tensor.tests.test_basic.ArctanhTester)
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/tests/test_basic.py", line 483, in test_grad
>       eps=_grad_eps)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tests/unittest_tools.py", line 91, in verify_grad
>       T.verify_grad(op, pt, n_tests, rng, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 1709, in verify_grad
>       abs_tol, rel_tol)
>   GradientError: GradientError: numeric gradient and analytic gradient exceed tolerance:
>           At position 4 of argument 0,
>               abs. error = 3.537018,  abs. tolerance = 0.010000
>               rel. error = 0.013429,  rel. tolerance = 0.010000
>   Exception args:
>   The error happened with the following inputs:, [array([[ 0.28898013,  0.98691875, -0.37341487],
>          [-0.83661169, -0.99454761, -0.57619613]], dtype=float32)],
>   The value of eps is:, None,
>   The out_type is:, None, Test Elemwise{arctanh,no_inplace}::normal: Error occurred while computing the gradient on the following inputs: [array([[ 0.28898013,  0.98691875, -0.37341487],
>          [-0.83661169, -0.99454761, -0.57619613]], dtype=float32)]
>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>   Ran 21747 tests in 7522.578s
>
> FAILED (SKIP=84, errors=2)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but this is what I did to make it work.

1. downgrade numpy to 1.9.x
2. reinstall pandas, matplotlib, ...
3. reinstall theano

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same problem; downgrading to numpy 1.9.3 (from 1.11.3) fixed it for me as well.  Re-upgrading to 1.11.3 brought the issue back, so this appears to be a bug in more recent numpy versions.  That's notwithstanding https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/theano-users/zyFc2DXMvpE/eblGjoa9AwAJ , in which Frederic Bastien (Theano developer) suggested that the error can be ignored and appears to be a test with too-strict error thresholds.